# Only Show Launch Button for Apple Push Notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to make the push notification payload so when the alert dialog pops up on the device there is only one "Launch" button that starts the app so the user can't dismiss the notification?

Our goal is to force the user to acknowledge critical messages by removing the option to dismiss the notification for these critical messages.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This would be fundamentally against Apple's user experience doctrine.  It would allow an app to effectively seize control of the device regardless of what a user is doing.